# Dealing with multiple languages in rss feed

Tags: php, utf-8, rss, lang

I am have problems dealing with different languages and codeignitors restful service by phil surgeon.

i am adding different language to my database which is set to utf-8unicode but when i pull it out its look random for some languages.

Like sinhalese
¹ç§°æžªå‡»æ¡ˆå«ŒçŠ¯å¯èƒ½ç»è¿‡è®­ç»ƒè£…å¤

Taken from gossip lanka their feed is
http://www.gossiplankanews.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss

is this todo with their feed? because i cant save a item to my database and then return it as sinhalese

any suggestions where the problem may lie?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data are actually in UTF-8 while your MySQL connexion  (I guess you have MySQL) is not configured to output UTF8.

In PHP, as soon as you've established the connexion you have to turn the connexion option to import/export as UTF8.

Like this :

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

Or with PDO :

```
$pdo = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=hostname;dbname=defaultDbName',
    'username',
    'password',
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
);
```

Comment: hi skrol29 thanks for the reply please look at my picture i have added its in the database like that do i need to decode it for output utf8_decode ?

Comment: First of all, check the collation of your database (schema), but also for the table, and also the columns. The actual collation is the one defined one the column. Schema and table collations are only default collations for fields.